# tkinter configure entry's pady

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to configure the "**`pady`**" keyword of entries that I have stored in a dictionary. But an error occurs every time I try to configure the `pady` keyword.

```
    for i in range(1, 4):
        temp = Entry(self.right_child, width=9)
        temp.insert(END, i)

        self.entries[f'{name}{i}'] = temp

        temp.grid(row=row, column=i-1, padx=(0,2), pady=(0,2))
```

All of my attempts shown below raises the same error

> `tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-pady"`

Here are my attempts:

```
self.entries['Afkastnignsgrad,%1']['pady'] = (0,25)         # 1
self.entries['Afkastnignsgrad,%1'].configure(pady = (0,25)) # 2
self.entries['Afkastningsgrad,%1'].config(pady = (0,25))    # 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: `pady` is not a valid option for an entry widget. `pady` is an option for the `grid` (and `pack`) command.

If you want to change the padding for a widget that was added to the display with `grid`, you must use `grid_configure`. For example:

```
self.entries['Afkastnignsgrad,%1'].grid_configure(pady=(0,25))
```